# Import more than one css file to html page

Tags: css, html, web, styles

I trying to import 2 css files as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/general.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
```

And for some reson its doesnt working, What would be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of loading css really matters, I think the bootstrap.css file has some class or id which has the same id as you have in general.css. The last css file will cover the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Correct! The order of loading css really matters. Please check the order you are loading and could you please post your exact issue? Like which part are you not able to get in your html page? @user11001